# unable to send information or click specific buttons on the website(selenium python)

Tags: python, html, selenium

I think this is more of my inability to read html of a specific website
I am trying to operate some things on this website:
https://fred.stlouisfed.org/series/DGS10

I am having 2 issues with it.

1. I tried to input the range of the date OR I also tried to put the range of the date at max by doing the either of the following(As long as I get 30 years of data or more I am ok). Below is my attempt to input a specific date and simulate pressing an enter-key on the keyboard.

```
range_search_bar = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id=\"input-cosd\"]")
range_search_bar.clear()
range_search_bar.send_keys("1980-10-10")
range_search_bar.send_keys(u'\ue007')
```

and below is an attempt to click the "max" date range button instead of inputting a date - I tried to do this first since this is simpler than the first code.

```
max_range_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id=\"zoom-all\"]")
max_range_button.click()
```

Unfortunately neither of them seem to change the range of the date...
I am suspecting that they are in a different iframe? But I could not find the iframe change...

2. I also tried to click the "download" button and then click the type "CSV(data)" button(which initiates the download) by doing the below code.

```
download_10_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id=\"download-button\"]/span")
download_10_button.click()
download_csv_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,("//*[@id=\"download-data-csv\"]"))
download_csv_button.click()
```

But I am getting this error : ElementNotInteractableException: element not interactable

Any ideas on what I might be doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: inside string `" "` you can use `' '` instead of `\" \"` like `"//*[@id='input-cosd']"` or you can use `" "` inside `' '` like `'//*[@id="input-cosd"]'`. It will be more readable.

Comment: did you try to use `time.sleep(...)` or [waits](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html) ? Sometimes script has to wait because JavaScript needs time to create objects in browser.

Answer (score 1):

I can download file if I use `time.sleep(...)` because JavaScript needs time to load data and to open menu when it clicks `Download`

```py
from selenium import webdriver
#from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager
import time

url = 'https://fred.stlouisfed.org/series/DGS10'

#driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=GeckoDriverManager().install())

driver.get(url)

time.sleep(5)

max_range_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="zoom-all"]')
max_range_button.click()

time.sleep(5)

download_10_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="download-button"]/span')
download_10_button.click()

time.sleep(2)

download_csv_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="download-data-csv"]')
download_csv_button.click()
```

Or you may use [waits](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html) for this.

But I still needed `sleep` to wait for loading all data.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
#from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager
import time

url = 'https://fred.stlouisfed.org/series/DGS10'

#driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=GeckoDriverManager().install())

driver.get(url)

time.sleep(5)

max_range_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="zoom-all"]')
max_range_button.click()

time.sleep(5)

download_10_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="download-button"]/span')))
download_10_button.click()

download_csv_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="download-data-csv"]')))
download_csv_button.click()
```

And the same with putting date

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
#from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException, TimeoutException
#from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager
import time

url = 'https://fred.stlouisfed.org/series/DGS10'

#driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=GeckoDriverManager().install())

driver.get(url)

time.sleep(5)

#max_range_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="zoom-all"]')
#max_range_button.click()

range_search_bar = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="input-cosd"]')
range_search_bar.clear()
range_search_bar.send_keys("1980-10-10")
range_search_bar.send_keys(Keys.ENTER) # u'\ue007')


time.sleep(5)
download_10_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="download-button"]/span')))
download_10_button.click()

download_csv_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="download-data-csv"]')))
download_csv_button.click()
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. I did have some wait timers implemented, but i apparently needed more. There was also a maintenance alert frame that blocked one of the click command. So I had to implement to close that as well and it worked.

Comment: `waits` can't detect when plot gets all data and displays it and this needs normal `sleep()` - or it would need some JavaScript code to detect new data.  But if it uses JavaScript to load data then maybe it could get data directly from server without using `Selenium`